# How to obtain a specific data from model in profile when person is logged in, Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to post a specific data in profile from user that is logged in.
I have a model like this:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)

class Wallet(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    usd = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

If for example 'user2' is logged in, and in database he has 10usd, I want in his profile to be shown 10usd.

But I don't know how to request a specific data of user that is logged in

**Views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='main')
def profile_user(request):
    usd = wallet.objects.get (get his usd from db)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'usd':usd})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get logged in user's id like this

```
user_id = request.user.id
```

then you can use it to fetch wallet details of that user

```
@login_required(login_url='main')
def profile_user(request):
    wallet_data= Wallet.objects.filter(name_id=user_id).values("usd").first()
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'usd':wallet_data['usd']})
```

another recommendation keep field name Proper related to FK Table name.
like you set `name = models.OneToOne` for User.
you should set it like

```
class Wallet(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    usd = models.FloatField(null=True)
```